# How to rearrange a date in python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a column in  a pandas data frame looking like:

```
test1.Received
Out[9]: 
0      01/01/2015 17:25
1      02/01/2015 11:43
2      04/01/2015 18:21
3      07/01/2015 16:17
4      12/01/2015 20:12
5      14/01/2015 11:09
6      15/01/2015 16:05
7      16/01/2015 21:02
8      26/01/2015 03:00
9      27/01/2015 08:32
10     30/01/2015 11:52
```

This represents a time stamp as Day Month Year Hour Minute. I would like to rearrange the date as Year Month Day Hour Minute. So that it would look like:

```
test1.Received
Out[9]: 
0      2015/01/01 17:25
1      2015/01/02 11:43
...
```

Comment: Do you want them as string?

Comment: as a string it should be fine. By using the function pd.to_datetime the string should turn again into a datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`pd.to_datetime`:](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime)

```
In [33]:
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
Out[33]:
index
0    2015-01-01 17:25:00
1    2015-02-01 11:43:00
2    2015-04-01 18:21:00
3    2015-07-01 16:17:00
4    2015-12-01 20:12:00
5    2015-01-14 11:09:00
6    2015-01-15 16:05:00
7    2015-01-16 21:02:00
8    2015-01-26 03:00:00
9    2015-01-27 08:32:00
10   2015-01-30 11:52:00
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

In your case:

```
pd.to_datetime(test1['Received'])
```

should just work

If you want to change the display format then you need to parse as a datetime and then `apply` `datetime.strftime:

```
In [35]:
import datetime as dt
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'))

Out[35]:
index
0     01/01/15 17:25:00
1     02/01/15 11:43:00
2     04/01/15 18:21:00
3     07/01/15 16:17:00
4     12/01/15 20:12:00
5     01/14/15 11:09:00
6     01/15/15 16:05:00
7     01/16/15 21:02:00
8     01/26/15 03:00:00
9     01/27/15 08:32:00
10    01/30/15 11:52:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```

So the above is now showing month/day/year, in your case the following should work:

```
pd.to_datetime(test1['Received']).apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

**EDIT**

it looks like you need to pass param `dayfirst=True` to `to_datetime`:

```
In [45]:
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'), dayfirst=True).apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'))

Out[45]:
index
0     01/01/15 17:25:00
1     01/02/15 11:43:00
2     01/04/15 18:21:00
3     01/07/15 16:17:00
4     01/12/15 20:12:00
5     01/14/15 11:09:00
6     01/15/15 16:05:00
7     01/16/15 21:02:00
8     01/26/15 03:00:00
9     01/27/15 08:32:00
10    01/30/15 11:52:00
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: I tried the first line of code but I got: TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'. The dtype of the column is object

Comment: You should've put in your post the dtype of your data, if it's a `str` already then `pd.to_datetime` will just parse this fine.

Comment: The problem is that when i do pd.to_datetime I get year day month and not year month day as I need

Comment: You'll need to perform a temporary conversion back to str and then to datetime I will post code

Comment: As you can see there is an error. if the result (Out[35]) shows month/day/year than the first two characters should be 01 for each of them while we got for rows 0 to 4 day month year and for the rest month day year. Also, in the first result (Out[33]) showing what supposedly is year day month we can see again that from line 5 onward it changes behavior turning to year month day.

Comment: try passing `dayfirst=True` to `to_datetime`, will update

Comment: `NameError: name 'dt' is not defined` on dt

Comment: @wprins sorry you need to add line `import datetime as dt`

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has this in-built, you can specify your datetime format
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html.
use `infer_datetime_format`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> i = pd.date_range('20000101',periods=100)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(year = i.year, month = i.month, day = i.day))
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.year*10000 + df.month*100 + df.day, format='%Y%m%d')
0    2000-01-01
1    2000-01-02
...
98   2000-04-08
99   2000-04-09
Length: 100, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `datetime` functions to convert from and to strings.

```
# converts to date 
datetime.strptime(date_string, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM')
```

and

```
# converts to your requested string format
datetime.strftime(date_string, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
date = ("15/8/1980")
s = date.split(/)
print(s)
if s == "DD MM YYYY":
   print("YYYY MM DD")
```

Comment: Hi iggy! Welcome to SO! Correct me if I'm wrong but this code doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**